# How to add auto height increase when keyboard is active so content is not overlapped for Maui Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, mudblazor, maui-blazor

I am building a Maui Blazor application which has inputs/dialogs (using MudBlazor), but when there is an input at the bottom of the page it is overlapped by keyboard. It is the same for popups/dialogs if it has inputs.

Is there any way to create a general solution for this?

I have tried to add different position styles for inputs but rather search a general solution, I mean if content is covered by keyboard then height is increased

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14197) what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, i have the same issue with bottom inputs and dialogs with inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android this solved the issue:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();

        Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
    }
}
```